# Is it possible to implement a site like Pinterest for internal (company) use on some CMS like drupal?

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, collaboration, pinterest

The popularity of pinterest has blown me away. I was wondering whether something similar can be created for internal use based on a content management system like drupal where different company employees can collaboratively pin sites ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we built a close replica of Pinterest in Drupal at ThemeSnap.com called PinBoard: http://www.themesnap.com/premium-drupal-themes/pinboard.html. I'm sure you can lock it down to only approved, role specified users to post there.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the main functionality of Pinterest can be implemented with the [module Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) (to Repin)